# Jquery ajax wait before fetching page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hellp people...lets take a simple ajax code...

```
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert(msg.html());
      });
```

I am Trying to fetch `msg.html()` after waiting for 5 seconds? so the process is as follows ...

1. send data to `some.php`
2. wait for 5 seconds
3. then return the html page data.

how can we achieve this?

Comment: You're looking for `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Slaks `setTimeout` do we have to give inside `.done` or `.success` function?

Comment: You call `setTimeout` whenever you want to start waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout`, The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. The function is only executed once.

And if you want to fetch the `html` of `msg` then first of all make sure `msg` is a valid HTML string and before fetching the `.html()` please convert it to a jQuery object by `$(msg)`.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: {
      name: "John",
      location: "Boston"
    }
  })
  .done(function(msg) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      alert($(msg).html());
    }, 5 * 1000);

  });
```

Comment: The reason for waiting is... my `some.php` will load data after 5 seconds(database fetching).... only after it loads i have to fetch the whole page html through ajax.. set timeout is enough to perform this action?

Comment: There are two things, 1.) Loading some.php after 5 seconds and then as it complete loading instantly alert. 2.) Load some.php and then after 5 seconds when it completely loads show the alert. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want to do 2.) Load some.php and then after 5 seconds when it completely loads show the alert.

Comment: Okay that's what i have done in my answer, and for this `setTimeout` will be sifficeint, see my updated answer.

Comment: @user3436481 Why don't you just have `some.php` return the data, instead of making a second call to load it?

Comment: @Barmar where is he making the second call?

Comment: He said above "after it loads I have to fetch the whole page html through ajax". That seems to be a second call.

Comment: `some.php` is an external url,,it has to fetch data based on parameters sent ... it takes around 3-5 seconds to fetch the data... we will return back the whole html sent by `some.php`

Comment: @Barmar where did he said `through ajax`? `msg` already has the html.

Comment: It's in the first comment below your answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url  : 'some.php',
      data :{ name : 'John', location : 'Boston'},
      beforeSend : function(){
        //you can do whatever you want here (loading gif etc.) until some.php responds 
      },
      complete : fuction(){
    //Here is for after responding
      },
      success : function(data){
      //data is the response of some.php, you can use the data to fill some elements in DOM etc.
    }


    });

    setTimeout(function(){
    //the codes you write here fires after 5 secs
    },5000);
```

and you can pass this where do you want.